# How can I override a wordpress parent theme function in my child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update the content of this parent theme function in my child theme but as soon as i copy it into the child theme functions.php file, i get this error in the browser "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

I just want to update the text in the body of the function. How can i do this please?

```
function oblique_footer_credits() {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'oblique' ) ) . '" rel="nofollow">';
    /* translators: WordPress */
        printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'oblique' ), 'WordPress' );
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<span class="sep"> | </span>';
    /* translators: 1 - Theme author 2 - Theme name */
    printf( __( 'Theme: %2$s by %1$s.', 'oblique' ), 'Themeisle', '<a href="http://themeisle.com/themes/oblique/" rel="nofollow">Oblique</a>' );
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'oblique_footer', 'oblique_footer_credits' );
```

Comment: what I do: change the name to be `<mytheme>_function_name` then call that function

Comment: it's probably due to the fact that your theme has the same function name and doesn't have a wrapper like. `if (!function_exists('oblique_footer_credits')) {..}`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! Im very new to PHP, sorry if this was a very basic question